# How do I do this in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I place 4 divs next to each other which width's will be calculated automatically (since every resolution of a monitor is different).

So whenever I have 16 divs, the amount shown div's still has to be 4.

I thought of giving a percentage, for each div. But that doesn't seem to be working (which is pretty obvious since every monitor has a different resolution of their screen displaying)

Comment: Use percentages or use some framework like [Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: If you're not opposed to using a framework, any number of them would handily help with this (e.g. Bootstrap, Foundation, or Materialize). Otherwise, I think a series of divs with width at 25% with display of inline-block inside a container with display of block should get you on the right path. Or there's always Flexboxes:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes.

Comment: Remember that the final width of the `div`s will be *width* + *padding* (spaced by margin) so to ensure you only get exactly 4 `div`s per row they'd have to have width 25% with padding and margin 0.

Comment: what problems are you having when you try to use percentages?

Comment: @andi whenever I use these percentages, a maximum of 3 div's will be shown. Not sure why though (maybe because of that the parent's div of where the div's are in, are also having 4 parent's div).

Comment: Maybe some jsfiddle will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a width using a percentage value (25%) which will put 4 boxes next to each other on each line.

```
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Well I actually ment, that the calculation of the amount of pixels will be calculated for each dif, using percentages will affect the "getting bigger" effect. So for example whenever I zoom out the page.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a framework like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

But this is the basic requirement you need to show 4 divs in a row...
just ignore the `background` and the `div:nth-child(even)` - I added that just so you could see the div areas clearly.

```css
section {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}
div {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  background: cornsilk;
}
div:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div>number 1</div>
<div>number 2</div>
<div>number 3</div>
<div>number 4</div>
<div>number 5</div>
<div>number 6</div>
<div>number 7</div>
<div>number 8</div>
<div>number 9</div>
<div>number 10</div>
<div>number 11</div>
<div>number 12</div>
<div>number 13</div>
<div>number 14</div>
<div>number 15</div>
<div>number 16</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Well I actually ment, that the calculation of the amount of pixels will be calculated for each dif, using percentages will affect the "getting bigger" effect. So for example whenever I zoom out the page.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle because I don't understand your issue?

Comment: It is a css with over 2000 lines of code, I could show you my problem in a test file instead? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can better use Bootstrap framework.
for example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="searcharea col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-3">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">4</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```